# EF Find() with multiple Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use Find() on a set of an EF class that has a foreign Key and 2 primary Keys, however I keep getting error.

This is my class:

```
public class dbDDV
    {
        [ForeignKey("dbf")]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public DateTime D0 { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public DateTime D1 { get; set; }

        public double V{ get; set; }
    }
```

For a particular value of id, D0 and D1 I have been trying to use Find():

```
dbContext.mySetOfdbDDV.Find(myId,myD0,myD1)
```

The following is the error I receive:

> System.ArgumentException: The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

What would be the correct approach for Find() on this case?

Comment: id is needed as well. I ended up adding [Key] to the id column so as to be both primary and foreign key which allowed me to use Find as originally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only `D0` and `D1` are part of your composite primary key (not `id`, as weird as that is, but I'm not here to judge your design).  So you should only pass values for those 2 columns when invoking `Find`

```
dbContext.mySetOfdbDDV.Find(myD0,myD1)
```

Comment: This worked. In my implementation I ended up changing the design adding [Key] to the id column so as to be both primary and foreign key.